# How to select the values of multiple columns in sorted order in mssql?

Tags: sql-server

In a table there are three columns, each containing numeric values (in my case representing length, width and height, but could be anything).

How can I select them, ordered by their value?

For example, given the values:

```
id | length | width | height
1  | 100    | 30    | 50
2  | 6      | 12    | 9
```

Expected output would be:

```
id | min    | mid   | max
1  | 30     | 50    | 100
2  | 6      | 9     | 12
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make the values of columns `length`, `width` and `height` to one column using **`union`**. And then use this result-set as a sub-query and give a row number based on group by `id` and descending order of the newly added column. Then by using a **`CASE`** expression take the row having row number 1 as `max`, 2 as `mid` and 3 as `min`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by t.[id]
        order by t.[new_col] desc
    ), *
    from (
        select [id], [length] as [new_col] from [your_table_name]
        union all
        select [id], [width] from [your_table_name]
        union all
        select [id], [height] from [your_table_name]
    ) t
)
select [id],
max(case [rn] when 1 then [new_col] end) as [max],
max(case [rn] when 2 then [new_col] end) as [mid],
max(case [rn] when 3 then [new_col] end) as [min]
from cte
group by [id];
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91214/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) with ORDER BY to get the relevent values in sorted order.

Using OFFSET X ROWS and FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY, you can access a specific position inside the sorted column values.

Use it repeatedly (increasing OFFSET by 1 in each step) to access the sorted column values at each position.

```
SELECT
  length,
  width,
  height,

  (
    SELECT dimensions
    FROM ( VALUES (length),(width),(height) ) AS compare(dimensions)
    ORDER BY dimensions ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
  ) AS minDimension,

  (
    SELECT dimensions
    FROM ( VALUES (length),(width),(height) ) AS compare(dimensions)
    ORDER BY dimensions ASC
    OFFSET 1 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
  ) AS midDimension,

  (
    SELECT dimensions
    FROM ( VALUES (length),(width),(height) ) AS compare(dimensions)
    ORDER BY dimensions ASC
    OFFSET 2 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
  ) AS maxDimension

FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternate solution, using `PERCENTILE_CONT` to obtain the Median:

```
WITH Measurement AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,100,30,50),
                 (2,6,12,9)) V(ID, [Length], Width, Height)),
Pvt AS(
    SELECT ID,
           D.Measurement AS MeasurementType,
           CASE WHEN D.Measurement = 'Length' THEN M.[Length]
                WHEN D.Measurement = 'Width' THEN M.Width
                WHEN D.Measurement = 'Height' THEN M.Height
           END AS Measurement
    FROM Measurement M
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Length'),('Width'),('Height')) D(Measurement)),
Median AS(
    SELECT ID,
           PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Measurement) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Median,
           MeasurementType, Measurement
    FROM Pvt)
SELECT ID,
       MIN(Measurement) AS [Min],
       Median,
       MAX(Measurement) AS [Max]
FROM Median
GROUP BY ID, Median
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 SQL Server supports `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()` which is how I've done this in MySQL. You can use those two functions to get `max` and `min` and then a bit of deductive reasoning using `CASE WHEN`.  The following query will work for both MySQL and recent versions of SQL Server:

```
SELECT
    LEAST(length, width, height) AS min,
    CASE
        WHEN length = GREATEST(length, width, height) THEN GREATEST(width, height)
        WHEN width = GREATEST(length, width, height) THEN GREATEST(length, height)
        ELSE GREATEST (length, width)
    END AS mid,
    GREATEST(length, width, height) AS max
FROM dimensions;
```

This also works when 2 or more values are the same. Here is a fiddle demonstrating: https://dbfiddle.uk/zu8NuqoO

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    [Length] INT,
    Width INT,
    Height INT
)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES(1,100,30,50),(2,6,9,12)

;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Val = [Length]
        FROM @T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Id,
        Val = Width
        FROM @T

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Id,
        Val = Height
        FROM @T
),C2
AS
(
SELECT
    SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Val),
    Id,
    Val
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT
    Id,
    [1] "min",
    [2] "mid",
    [3] "max"
    FROM C2
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(VAL)
        FOR
        SeqNo IN
        (
            [1],[2],[3]
        )
    )q
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

Query

```
declare @table table (id integer, length integer, width integer, height integer)

insert into @table select 1,100,30,50
insert into @table select 2,6,12,9

select id, MIN(a) min
,(select top 1 max(c.a) from
    (
    select id,length a from @table
    union all
    select id,width a from @table
    union all
    select id,height a from @table
    )c
where c.id = b.id and c.a <> max(b.a) and c.a <> min(b.a) group by c.id) mid, max(a) max
from
(
    select id,length a from @table
    union all
    select id,width a from @table
    union all
    select id,height a from @table
)b
group by id
```